# Move the location of "Notify user of new account" from bottom to custom section of admin/people screen?

Tags: users, hooks

Is it possible in **Drupal 7** to move the location of "Notify user of new account" checkbox from the bottom of the page to another location on the admin user screen? I have a custom module with hook_form_user_alter. I have no problem hiding it from appearing, but I didn't know if I could move it to another location on the form and how would I go about doing that if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, it's $form['notify']. So you should be able to do this:

```
$form['notify']['#weight'] = -999;
```